# Using Baltimore City Survey Control System?

Tags: coordinate-system, united-states, epsg

A client has provided some surveyed points referenced to the "BALTIMORE CITY
SURVEY CONTROL SYSTEM", they're all projected and given in easting/northing numbers. I need to reconcile them with some GPS coordinates I have in the NAD83 (2011).

I'm new to the GIS world, and really don't want to ask the client any stupid questions, but I can't figure out what the transformation is going to be.

Should I ask them for an EPSG code?

Comment: What GIS software are you using? What do you mean by points, a table, a shapefile etc.?

Comment: I'm using the Trimble suite, TBC specifically. The points are just north, east, elevation coordinates in a spreadsheet.

Comment: You need to know the coordinate system of the survey Points (name or EPSG code)

Comment: It seems that the Baltimore County adopted the Maryland Coordinate System, North America Datum of 1983. So it should be EPSG:6487 (meters) or EPSG:6488 (US survey feet).

Comment: Info here: http://archive.baltimorecity.gov/OfficeoftheMayor/MayoralOffices/InformationTechnology/EnterpriseGeographicInformationServices/PublicAccessData.aspx . Note: city of Baltimore system is not in EPSG. It's also in spatialreference.org . If you're not using Esri, you may have trouble converting the definition into something that can be used.

Comment: http://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/7898/proj4/ seems to be close, but missing the `XY_Plane_Rotation`. If you could supply a few test points in degrees and projected, I could try to resolve this.

Comment: I should have the lat/long in NAD83 by the end of the week, ill post them if anyone is still interested. Are there any free tools that I could plug transformation data into, I saw a couple python packages that look like they might work? We don't have Esri. Thanks for the help all.

Comment: (Almost) all free tools are based on PROJ.4, but nobody has taken care of the Baltimore CSCS yet, because it is not on the EPSG database..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by @mkennedy:

> Info here:
>   http://archive.baltimorecity.gov/OfficeoftheMayor/MayoralOffices/InformationTechnology/EnterpriseGeographicInformationServices/PublicAccessData.aspx
>   . Note: city of Baltimore system is not in EPSG. It's also in
>   spatialreference.org . If you're not using Esri, you may have trouble
>   converting the definition into something that can be used.

and @AndreJ:

> (Almost) all free tools are based on PROJ.4, but nobody has taken care
>   of the Baltimore CSCS yet, because it is not on the EPSG database.